# How can I style class of child component vuejs

Tags: vue.js, sass

I am using /deep/ to style a class of a child component that I am using in my view. I am using scss. My code:

```
/deep/ .popover {
  position: fixed;
}
```

I get this error:
[image: Deep Error]

Comment: `/deep/` is deprecated, you shouldn't be using it

Comment: @DerekPollard so what should I be using instead?

Comment: Looks like there's documentation around this issue: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors